# Remover item de uma lista simplesmente encadeada

Tags: c++, estrutura-de-dados, lista-encadeada

Estou com dificuldade para remover um item pelo valor de uma lista simplesmente encadeada. Eu estou fazendo assim:

```
class No{
    public:
    int dado;
    No *next;
    No(int item, No *ptr= NULL){
        dado=item;
        next=ptr;
    }
};

class Lista{
    public:
        Lista(){
        first = last = NULL;
    };
    bool listaVazia();
    void inserirInicio(int item);
    void inserirFim(int item);
    void inserirPosicao(int item, int posicao);
    void buscaItem(int item);
    void removeInicio();
    void removeFim();
    void removeItem(int item);
    void imprimirLista();
    int tamanhoLista = 0;
    private:
    No *first, *last;
};
```

Eu já consigo verificar na função se ela esta inserindo no inicio e no final, eu preciso entender como eu vou remover de uma posição no meio para ela não se perder:

```
void Lista::inserirPosicao(int item,int posicao){
    if(posicaoValida(posicao)){
        if(posicao == 1){ // INSERI NA PRIMEIRA POSICAO
        inserirInicio(item);
    }else{
        if(last->next == NULL){ // INSERI NA ULTIMA POSICAO
            inserirFim(item);
            return;
        }else{ //   INSERIR NO MEIO


        }

    }
    }else{
       cout << endl << "       POSICAO INVALIDA" << endl;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Você já tem um método para percorrer a lista? Ele pode achar um item pela sua posição? Você precisa disto primeiro. Eliminar o último é fácil e acho que está conseguindo, é só anular ele e obviamente decrementar o tamanho. O problema é que você precisa mudar o elemento anterior da lista que ele não tem mais um próximo. E como ela não é duplamente encadeada você não tem essa informação. Então terá que percorrer toda a lista até chegar no que era o penúltimo elemento e anular o ponteiro de próximo.

Comment: Não coloque código em comentário, edite a pergunta e coloque toda informação que puder. Para deletar basta torná-lo nulo.

Comment: @bigown nesta ultima função removeItem(item) eu preciso localizar o item e remove-lo, para isto eu fiz um while percorrendo e um if verificando se o item bate com um valor, se sim eu devo remove-lo e fazer o anterior apontar para o proximo no

Comment: Você mudou a pergunta. Você precisa acessar dois itens para remover: tem que descobrir o item a ser removido; vai pegar o `next` contido nele; vai anular todo o nó; vai jogar o `next` obtido nele e vai mudar o `next` do nó anterior com esse `next`, assim o anterior vai apontar para o próximo. è bem simples. Eu só não respondo porque estou com pouco tempo agora e não posso testar. Se você colocar um código que dê para eu testar eu vejo se dá para mudar o que precisa, se possível faça no http://ideone.com/

Comment: o codigo e feita em duas `.h`, aqui esta o codigo: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByiDi-nlXfgVWHB3VzFPUE40Zk0&authuser=0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu fiz um código básico. Não analisei todo seu código e não fiz testes extensivos. Pode ter situações que não funcione. Como eu teria tomado várias decisões diferentes eu preferi tentar manter do jeito que você vinha fazendo e nem analisei se algumas coisas não estão ideal, até porque me parece que você está aprendendo e isto é secundário.

```
void Lista::removeItem(int item){
    if(listaVazia()){
       cout << endl << "       LISTA VAZIA" << endl;
    //se tem um item ou já é o primeiro, desvie o quanto antes para removeInicio
    } else if(tamanhoLista == 1 || first->dado == item) {
        removeInicio();
        return;
    } else {
        No *ant = first; //já inicializei o nó anterior com o primeiro item
        No *atu = ant->next; //o nó atual com o próximo nó
        while(atu != NULL){
            if(atu->dado == item) {
                break; //se achou não precisa continuar procurando
            } else { //já que vai analisar outro item, então atualiza os nós
                ant = atu; //agora o anterior é o item atual
                atu = atu->next; //o atual passa ser o próximo item da lista
            }
        }
        if(atu != NULL) { //se chegou no fim sem achar nada, nada deve ser feito
            if (last == atu) { //se é o último que está removendo
                last = ant;
            }
           ant->next = atu->next; //atualiza a lista pegando o próximo do atual
           delete atu; //mata o atual
           tamanhoLista--;
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/RaINWm). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/inzqjdsf-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Algorithm/RemoveLinkedList.cpp).

O `removeFim` agora pode ser bem simplificado já que o objeto sabe qual é o último. Então nele basta chamar o `removeItem` acima passando como argumento o `dado` do `last` da lista.

Comment: consegui as duas agora so falta InserirPosicao,

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues Abra outra pergunta para outro problema. Não fique editando a pergunta para mudar o problema. Cada problema é uma pergunta. Isto resolveu o problema? Você está satisfeito com ela para esse problema? Acha que merece um boto e aceitação? Está querendo esperar se aparece outras soluções para aceitar?

Comment: estava esperando uma ideia de como implementar a inserirPosicao, que foi um dos metodos citados a principo, bom, o que voce citou esta 100 porcento, apenas vou terminar as soluções para dar o voto de aceitação

Comment: Para fazer o inserir usa uma ideia semelhante, se fizer a pergunta sobre ele eu respondo assim que der.

Comment: consegui resolver :D