# Deletar um espaço alocado por malloc

Tags: c, alocação

Primeiramente aloquei 6 espaços de 52 bytes pertencentes a uma struct na memória:

```
lista = malloc(6 * sizeof(registro));
```

Na prática para acessa-los via ponteiro é feito:

```
lista[0], lista[1], lista[2]...
```

E como eu faria para deletar o conteúdo guardado no espaço `lista[2]`? Deixando os outros 5 espaços intactos?

Comment: Você vai precisar "reordenar" os elementos (trazendo tudo depois de `lista[2]` uma posição para baixo e então usar [`realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) ou usar algo como [`memmove`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memmove/). Uma estrutura com ponteiros é mais flexível quando precisamos fazer esse tipo de remoção "no meio" do espaço reservado.

Comment: Tem um exemplo aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/54608/101 Não é a mesma coisa porque é uma lista ligada, mas dá uma ideia. Tem um em Java que é mais próximo do que precisa fazer (não que seja o melhor algoritmo): http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/127008/101. Se eu achar outra, eu posto aqui.

Comment: Trazer tudo para uma posição anterior já está além do que eu quero, preciso ao menos liberar aquele espaço de memória, com free(), porém apenas colocar free(lista[2]); não funciona

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a função `memmove()` da biblioteca padrão `string.h` combinado com a função `realloc()` da biblioteca padrão `stdlib.h`, veja só como ficaria a solução do seu caso:

```
registro * lista = NULL;

/* Aloca vetor de registro com 6 elementos */
lista = (registro*) malloc( 6 * sizeof(registro) );

/* Desloca os 3 ultimos elementos do vetor */
memmove( &lista[2], &lista[3], sizeof(registro) * 3 );

/* Realoca a memoria sem alterar os dados do vetor */
lista = (registro*) realloc( lista, 5 * sizeof(registro_t) );

...

/* libera a memoria alocada */
free(lista);
```

Comment: Não tem nenhuma observação no `memmove` que diz que, caso haja sobreposição de regiões de memória, o comportamento é inesperado?

Comment: Tem uma observação que diz que pode haver sobreposição que o comportamento será feito de maneira adequada, na verdade. Devo ter confundido com outra função, possivelmente de outra linguagem

Answer (score 0):

Quando você faz uma chamada de malloc, em termos simplificados o SO guarda um registro da posição de memória que te foi entregue para uso e quantos bytes a partir dela estão disponíveis. Assim, fazer algo como `free(&lista[2])` (faltou o indicador de endereço) não funciona, porque esse endereço não foi devolvido por uma chamada de malloc, apenas coincide de se encontrar na faixa dos 6 * 52 bytes a partir do endereço registrado.

Vetores são espaços contíguos de memória, e não tão flexíveis quanto listas. Se você quer liberar o espaço de `lista[2]`, o jeito é fazer como o Anthony citou: realocar e mover. Mas tenha em mente que isso altera a posição dos índices originais e começa a ficar custoso em vetores grandes.

Alternativamente, há uma solução mais simples: fazer um vetor de ponteiros para struct. Assim cada posição dele ocuparia no máximo 8 bytes (o que te permitiria só liberar no final do programa, se não estiver muito preocupado com memória) e daria certo fazer algo como `free(lista[2])` (neste caso, você não estaria liberando a posição do vetor, mas sim o endereço apontado pelo ponteiro da struct na memória).

Comment: Mas "lista", já é um ponteiro pra estrutura. Sendo o nome da minha estrutura: "registro", eu declaro o mesmo: `registro *lista;`.

Comment: Não sei se entendi muito bem... lista é um ponteiro para estrutura, mas você está acessando como se fosse um vetor?

Comment: Assim, lista é um ponteiro para a estrutura, então eu faço uma alocação dinâmica usando lista. Como citada la em cima `lista = malloc(6 * sizeof(registro));`, estou alocando 6 espaços, cada um com o tamanho da estrutura, e para acessar cada um eu uso: `lista[0]`, `lista[1]`... `lista[5]`.

Comment: Entendi. Mas nesse caso, cada espaço é um valor, não um ponteiro. A solução que eu sugeri envolveria declarar lista como ponteiro de ponteiros `registo **lista`, fazer o malloc para o vetor e, para cada posição (que guarda agora um ponteiro), você faz um malloc para a struct. Isso te permitiria dar `free(lista[i])` quando tal posição se tornasse desnecessária para ti.